# XPath: How to select script between other scripts with no attributes?

Tags: xpath

I try to select a specific script on the adobe air download site
https://get.adobe.com/de/air/download/?installer=Adobe_AIR_30.0_for_Win32&stype=7645&standalone=1 (look out download should start)

Problem is the script I'm trying to get has no attributes and is between some other scripts.

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/uber/js/pdc_s_code.js"></script>
   <script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/659ec8ada5450db95675e43beaaae92399591a11/satelliteLib-7123a14bc11ffd1ad43be190a593a8932494dcb0.js"></script>
  
             <script>                
                     
     setTimeout("location.href = 'https://airdownload.adobe.com/air/win/download/30.0/AdobeAIRInstaller.exe';", 2000);
                
    
                $(function() {
                    $("#whats_new_panels").bxSlider({
                        controls: false,
                        auto: true,
                        pause: 15000
                    });
                });
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#download_messaging").hide();
                    $("#next_button").show();
                }, 10000);
            </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/downloadcenter/js/live/polarbear.js"></script>
```

I'm able to get the first and fourth one with

`/html/body/script[1]` and
`/html/body/script[2]`

but I don't know how to get the one I actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
//script[not(@*)]
```

to select `script` node with no attributes